# JSON output format after join two tables in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have two tables, `Table1` and `Table2` where one Field is common between them.  I have classes for each, and have created relationships between them.

Now in the `get` operation I need to format the JSON output, as shown below:

```
{
  Table1: [{
    id: 1111
    Name:xyz 
    table2: [{
      id:222
      Table1_id:111
      address:add1
    },
    {
      id: 223 
      Table1_id:111 
      add:add1
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 hash = Hash.new
 array = Array.new
 table1.each do |table|
   temp = Hash.new 
   temp[:name] = table.name
  temp[:id]= table.id
     temp[:table2] = table.table2s.select(:id,:table1_id,:add1add1)
   array << temp 
end
hash[:table1]= hash
```

You can use ruby array for json [ ] ruby hash for json { }

Comment: Thanks Pitabas. I am able to get output in required format.